# Jquery UI Sortable - Child element moves parent items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box__title">
            <div class="box__move">move</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box__description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box__title">
            <div class="box__move">move</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box__description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like "box__move" to be the trigger to move "box" items within the "wrapper".

I was hoping something like the following might work, but hasn't. So, wondering if there is actually a way to do this.

```
$('.box__move').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    items: 'parent .box'
});
```

Anyone able to assist, or is this not possible?

Comment: You would like "box__move" to be the trigger to move "box" items within the "wrapper". So you mean you want the user to click on box__move?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The user would click on the "box__move" to drag "box"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.wrapper').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.box__move'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.box__move'
});
```